# print a range of lines if they match a pattern

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

My input

```
1
abc

1cde
efg
xxx

1
abc
pattern1
pattern2

efg
xxx

1
abc
cde
efg
xxx
```

my expected output (print from 1 it contains pattern1 and 2):

```
1
abc
pattern1
pattern2

efg
xxx
```

I have so for:

```
sed -n '/^1/ {x;/pattern1/ {N;/\n.*pattern2/p};d} $/^1/ {h;/pattern1/ {N;/\n.*pattern2/p};d}}H' My file
```

BTW my file is a very big file, please show me a method that can do it quickly.
Thanks so much.

Comment: Explain how to get that output from your posted sample input or fix your example if you can't get your posted output from your posted input..

Answer (score 3):

sed is for `s/old/new/` - that is all. For anything else you should be using awk.

It looks like your expected output can't actually be produced from your sample input so it's a guess and untested since we don't have anything concrete to test against but it sounds like you might want:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/pattern1/ && /pattern2/' file
```